# Scala: How can I combine/merge 2 mutable maps?

Tags: scala, hashmap, scala-collections

I have a method:

```
def mergeMaps(map1: mutable.Map[K, V], 
              map2: mutable.Map[K, V]): mutable.Map[K, V] = {
       // merge logic here
       m1
}
```

I tried using Scalaz but for some reason, it says symbol |+| cannot be found. NOTE: I imported scalaz._ and Scalaz._

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate two maps as follows:
`m1 ++ m2`
so, your  function should look like this,

`def mergeMaps(map1: mutable.Map[K, V], map2: mutable.Map[K, V]): mutable.Map[K, V] = {
       // merge logic here
       m1 ++ m2
}`

This blog post (http://scala4fun.tumblr.com/post/84792374567/mergemaps) could help. I'm not really sure about the imports but as I currently understand it, this is the conventional way to merge two maps. Also, are you merging these maps by key?, if so, there is a way to do that in Scala. I hope this helps.